# Need help with logarithmic differentitation

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I have the expression

$$y = \sqrt{x^2(x+1)(x+2)}.$$

I have tried looking at videos but I still cannot arrive at the correct answer and don't know how to get there.

By the way, the correct answer is

$$y' = \frac{4x^2+9x+4}{2\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}}.$$

Please, help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively, write $$y^2=x^2(x+1)(x+2)$$

Then $$2yy'=2x(x+1)(x+2)+x^2(x+1)+x^2(x+2)$$ whence

$$y'=\frac{2x(x+1)(x+2)+x^2(x+1)+x^2(x+2)}{2x\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}}$$

$$y'=\frac{2(x+1)(x+2)+x(x+1)+x(x+2)}{2\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}}\\=\frac{4x^2+9x+4}{2\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}}$$

assuming you wanted $x\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}$ since $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and we get something not that nice with that.

Comment: ....That was awesome. Just one question though and forgive me, I'm slow. What happened to the first x term in the original equation for y? I understand your substitution method

Comment: you know the x^2 term

Comment: @user89477 It was cancelled with the common $x$ in $2x,x^2,x^2$ above. Note my commentary on writing $y=x\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}$.

Comment: Amazing... that actually helped a lot to rewrite the function in that fashion. Thank you tremendously.

Answer (score 5):

$$y = \sqrt{x^2 (x+1)(x+2)}$$

$$\ln{y} = \ln{x} + \frac12 \ln{(x+1)} + \frac12 \ln{(x+2)}$$

$$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac12 \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac12 \frac{1}{x+2}$$

$$y' = x \sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)} \left (  \frac{1}{x} + \frac12 \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac12 \frac{1}{x+2}\right) = x \sqrt{(x+1) (x+2)} \left ( \frac{4 x^2+9 x+4}{2 x(x+1)(x+2)}\right)$$

which I believe works out to your answer.

Comment: I appreciate the input but I guess my help is needed with the algebra portion. Such as how did you get from the third line to the forth line to the fifth?

Comment: @user89477: To get from the 3rd to the 4th line, I multiplied by the original $y$; there is very little algebra done there.  To get from the 4th to the 5th line, I found the least common denominator of the fractions.  For example, I multiplied $1/x$ up and down by $2 (x+1) (x+2)$, etc.  I then expanded the binomial products in the numerator that resulted and got the expression in the numerator.

Comment: while I still don't understand the problem completely you did help me understand a little more. Thank you for your work

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the following much simpler?
$$y = \sqrt{x^4+3x^3+2x^2}$$
$$y' = \frac{4x^3+9x^2+4x}{2x\sqrt{(x+1)(x+2)}}$$ and cancelling out the $x$ from both terms gives the desired result.